# Disable keyboard shortcut in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am using something like this:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
  // code
}
```

For switching photos in photoalbum with arrow keys.. It works great, but!
I want to disable in textarea. Because, if I am commenting a photo and I want to move cursor with arrow keys, I switch photo and lose my text :)

How to disable it? Can I catch, which element is focused?
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check to see if the target element is a textarea.

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if ( target.tagName !== "TEXTAREA" ) {
        // code
    }
});
```

Comment: "e.target.type" also worked for me.